# bootstrap or tukey's hsd?

Tags: bootstrap, tukey-hsd-test

I have several groups of measurements like shown below, and I want to know of the distance from each group to the overall mean is significantly different from the rest. Can I do a bootstrap where I just draw distances from the total group of distances measured, and set 95% confidence from that? Or should I instead use Tukey's HSD to determine the points where distance is different?

[image]

[image]

Comment: Are you interested in comparing each mean to each other mean as is done with Tukey or each mean to the mean of the other groups?

Comment: I think each mean to each other mean as in Tukey - I want to determine which points have significantly larger distance than expected by chance.

Comment: Tukey HSD is a good choice. Contrary to popular opinion, you don't have to do an ANOVA first since the Tukey HSD fully controls the Type I error rate. Just don't call it post hoc since in your case, there is nothing post hoc about it.

Answer (score 1):

Tukey's test, following an omnibus ANOVA test is the way to go, assuming you meet the assumptions of the ANOVA test.

Comment: if the data are weakly dependent, would I be better off using a bootstrap?

Comment: You could go simpler in that case and use a non-parametric multiple comparison test like the Kruskal – Wallis test.

Comment: Tukey's HSD and bootstrap p-value adjustment are general ways to test for multiplicity.along with many others.  I don't think the reasons given are justification for picking one over the other.  Sometimes considerations like simplicity or how conservative the test is.  As I say many times when issues of multiplicity come up take a look at Westfall and Young's 1993 book published by Wiley.  It emphasizes permutation and bootstrap methods  but also considers Bonferroni and some other methods.  If you are in a situation where you are interested in an FDR criteria check other literature on that

Comment: FDR stands for False Discovery Rate.

Comment: I think I am not quite looking to do multiple comparisons - for each point I just want to know if it is different from the overall mean distance across all the measured data, rather than whether it is different from each other point or which other points it is different from.

Comment: @user144685 It is natural to think that you at least have multiple comparisons under consideration since you mention Tukey's HSD which is a multiple comparison method.  Also the bootstrap can be applied in many ways.  I naturally thought you were referring to p-value adjustment.  If not what way were you planning to use the bootstrap.

Comment: I have time-series data (added a picture) where I want to show that the circled points are different from the overall mean of all measurements. multiple comparison tests would require that each circled point be different from every other point, which seems to be too stringent a requirement?    my thinking with bootstrapping was that it would give a distribution of values from which I could then determine a p-value for the circled points.